# user contol textbox value to datagrid

Tags: c#

there are two usercontrol in my form as **label textbox datepicker**
1st label=From date
2nd label=TO date
there is also one data grid and one button
now i wnt **data between two dates in datagrid as from two textboxes in user control**
i m trying this code but it is not working:

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IRIS-CSG-174;Initial Catalog=library_system;Integrated Security=True");
            cs.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between'" + userControl11+ "'" + "and'" + userControl12.Text + "'", cs);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "lib_issue_details");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", ds, "lib_issue_details"));

            cs.Close();
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean "is not working"?
btw. Did you read the answers to your previous questions? Why don't you use parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the labels have right date format, you are missing `.Text` on `userControl11`

Try

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between'" + userControl11.Text + "'" + "and'" + userControl12.Text + "'", cs);
```

And couple things not related your question. Look into parametrized queries rather than concatenating values into the query string. Also a better practice is to use `using` for IDisposable entities like this

```
using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(...) )
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply...but now it is showing only database header columns not the values between two dates...help me as what i m missing in it

Comment: @Raghav try the same query in management studio (if you are using sql server) and see if you get any rows back.

Comment: Do you have records for the specified range ?

Comment: Try `da.Fill(ds);` instead of `da.Fill(ds, "lib_issue_details");`

Comment: yes when i try it in sql server dates between par dates will return and it is not working with da.Fill(ds).i think i need to define usercontrol textbox value smwhere.how to define it as values from user control textbox may return

Comment: This above code is workng when i m using textbox 1 and text box2 but now i wnt to do it with user control and it is not working!!!some code is written to define user control textbox value..!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your command text:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select * from dbo.lib_issue_details 
    where book_issue_on between'" + userControl11.Text+ "' and '" + 
    userControl12.Text + "'", cs);
```